Is it possible to link implictly against an import lib and call a function exported by ordinal?
I know I can use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress passing the ordinal to call the function exported by ordinal at run time. But can I call the function at compiling/linking time?

What's the point of all of these questions? You'd better explain what you're trying to pull here (and what the (main) problem is), instead of coming with all kinds of scenarios and assumptions.
